# Too-many-arguments error when creating Thread with one argument

Tags: python

this is basically the code

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
import os
import threading

from requests import Response

def search(ip_adress):
    comando="ping -c 1 " +ip_adress
    response=os.popen(comando).read()

if "1 received" in Response:
       print("Encontrado en : ", ip_address)

for ip in range(1,254):
    current_ip="192.168.1. "+str(ip)
    run=threading.Thread(target=search , args = (current_ip))

run.start()
```

and the error that appears

```
C:/Users/Macaco/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe f:/Desktop/project/pythonprojts/redes_local.py
Exception in thread Thread-1 (search):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Macaco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Macaco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: search() takes 1 positional argument but 14 were given
```

Comment: `args = (current_ip)` is not a tuple—it's just one value, so this splits up the input into characters. Try `args = (current_ip, )` <- note the comma.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the argument passing in the thread creation

```
run=threading.Thread(target=search , args = (current_ip))
```

Putting `()` around `current_ip` doesn't make a sequence containing `current_ip`, instead it treats `current_ip` as the sequence of args (using each character as a different argument). So it thinks you're passing 14 arguments instead of one 14-character string. What you have is equivalent to `args=current_ip`

For example, if `current_ip='192.168.1.101'` then it's like you're saying

```
args = ['1', '9', '2', '.', '1', '6', '8', '.', '1', '.', '1', '0', '1']
```

**You can fix this** a couple ways. One is to use `[]` to make it a `list`

```
run=threading.Thread(target=search , args = [current_ip])
```

Another is to add a trailing comma to make it into a tuple

```
run=threading.Thread(target=search , args = (current_ip,))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now I get a new error, I don't know if I'm moving forward or backward, but if you can help me with this new error:   File "f:\Desktop\project\pythonprojts\redes_local.py", line 12, in search
    if "1 received" in Response:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Comment: @FrancoRamirezCastillo forward, because you're in the thread now. It's hard for me to speculate what the right solution is without knowing what your goal is but you're using capital R "Response" which is the type. Your `if` needs to be indented, and then maybe what you want is `if "1 received" in response.text:`

Comment: no, actually I take that back because you're not using the requests library to actually send the request. It looks to me like you're trying to combine two different tutorials and have made something that doesn't do the right thing for either. I suggest following one guide [like this](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#the-response) If you want to use the requests library. If you want to use `popen` then you should use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and not os.popen

Comment: It is to scan the IP that are connected to my Wi-Fi network, I took the script from YouTube, but if you recommend other python libraries to scan IP on my network, I would appreciate it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spGUEdavm1Y 
It is in Spanish, but the code is shown at the end, the script runs well for the guy, but not for me

Comment: @FrancoRamirezCastillo [maybe one of these `nmap` suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/311019/display-list-of-computers-on-a-lan-in-linux)? And then wrap with `subprocess.run`?